# html not working after php script?

Tags: php, html

hi i am doing a web and after i check if a session is set for see if is loged or not the body is not working of the html, the code:

```
<?php 
 session_start();
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if( !isset($_SESSION["username"]) ){




        echo "<p id='errors'>Por favor, loguese, si no se redirecciona haz click <a href='log.php'>aqui</a></p>";

        exit();


}else{
    exit();
};
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">

</head>

<body>
   test
</body>
</html>
```

as you can see the word "test" should be on the body but in the web there isnt what can i do ?

Comment: `else{ exit(); }` Stops the script. Nothing is done after that.

Comment: You `exit` before the HTML whether the condition is true or false!

Comment: Don't put the solution in the question. Accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

The `exit()` function closes the output buffer. So nothing behind it is executed or displayed.

[Ouput buffer control](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php)

Answer (score 0):

You use `exit();` in both cases of your if/else condition. This stops the output before the HTML part even begins...

Answer (score 0):

Put only this

`if( !isset($_SESSION["username"]) ){`

```
    echo "<p id='errors'>Por favor, loguese, si no se redirecciona haz click <a href='log.php'>aqui</a></p>";

    exit();
```

`}`

without `else`